# What does CreateMany with seed do?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

What does the `CreateMany` overload with the `T seed` parameter actually do?  I've tried to seed, but the seed seems to have no effect on the created objects.  For example, I was expecting that if my seed had a property of type `string`, that either:

- the string value would be used to populate that property in all newly created objects
- or the string value would be used as a prefix when setting that property in all newly created objects

Answer (score 15, accepted):

#### tl;dr

As a general rule, AutoFixture [*does not guarantee*](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/SpecimenFactory.cs#L254-257) how seed values are going to be used during the creation process, if at all. This characteristic stems from the way AutoFixture [is designed](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Internal-Architecture).

#### Background

Every time AutoFixture is asked to create an object of a certain `Type`, the request is routed through [a pipeline of objects called "*builders*"](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Internal-Architecture#fixture-high-level-layout). Each builder is responsible for handling a certain kind of *request* (whether it be a request for a *concrete type*, an *interface*, a *property*, a *field* etc). If a builder encounters a request it can handle, it's going to return a value for it and the pipeline restarts with the next request.

Given the above, if you want to create an object based on a *seed*, all AutoFixture can do is make sure that the seed value you provide is [embedded in the request](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/Kernel/SeededRequest.cs) that is sent through the pipeline. Then it's up to the builders to decide what to do with that value.

#### Solution

AutoFixture currently comes with a *single builder* that takes into account seed values and that's [the one for strings](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/StringSeedRelay.cs#L7-L8).

However, you can tell AutoFixture how it should use seed values when creating objects of *any type* by customizing a `Fixture` specifically for that type with [the `FromSeed` method](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/Dsl/NodeComposer.cs#L41-L55):

```cs
var fixture = new Fixture();
fixture.Customize<Foo>(c =>
    c.FromSeed(seed =>
        {
            // return an instance of Foo
            // that uses the seed value in some way
        }));
```

The *factory function* you provide to `FromSeed` will be invoked every time AutoFixture has to create an instance of `Foo` and it will be passed the seed value from the `Fixture`. For example, given this:

```cs
fixture.CreateMany<Foo>(seed: new Foo { Bar = "baz" });
```

the `seed` parameter of the factory function will receive the `Foo` seed object that has the `Bar` property set to `"baz"`.

Comment: +1 FWIW, we're considering (re)moving the seed overloads in AutoFixture version 4 https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/151