# How to get AutoFixture create an integer that is >0, and not another number?

Tags: c#, random, int, autofixture

I want AutoFixture to generate two integers, and for the second one, I don't want it to be 0, or the previous generated number. Is there a way to tell AutoFixture to honor that "requirement".

Looking at `RandomNumericSequenceGenerator`, I looks like the [lower limit is 1](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/blob/master/Src/AutoFixture/RandomNumericSequenceGenerator.cs#L26), so I might not have to specify the first requirement. Next, I was looking at the "seeding" option, but as indicated in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28475970/471780), it won't be used for a number, by default.

Is there something I'm overlooking here?

Comment: Do you use plain-AutoFixture or AutoFixture.Xunit/NUnit?

Comment: Unfortunately, plain AutoFixture using MSTest. Why? And how would Xunit help, for example?

Comment: It's less boilerplate with AutoFixture.Xunit. See the [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32782299/467754) below.

Comment: Why not just use the `fixture.CreateMany(2)` ? As i understand from the documentation [link](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/wiki/Version-History#numbers-are-random) the second number will be always > 0 and not another number.

Comment: Good catch! Yes, that's easier and works by default, as @MarkSeemann [wrote](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32781002/how-to-get-autofixture-create-an-integer-that-is-0-and-not-another-number/32782299?noredirect=1#comment53405043_32782299). It should also be the accepted answer.

Comment: @AlexanderW I was apparently overlooking something indeed ;) My question had the hidden assumption that AutoFixture didn't do that, but apparently it already does exactly what I want ^_^

Comment: @Ties I asked it because i was also not sure. Anyway the problem is solved :)

Answer (score 20):

Here's a way to do this with plain AutoFixture:

```cs
[Fact]
public void GenerateTwoDistinctNonZeroIntegersWithAutoFixture()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();
    var generator = fixture.Create<Generator<int>>();

    var numbers = generator.Where(x => x != 0).Distinct().Take(2);
    // -> 72, 117
}
```

And here's a way to do this with [AutoFixture.Xunit](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AutoFixture.Xunit2):

```cs
[Theory, AutoData]
public void GenerateTwoDistinctNonZeroIntegersWithAutoFixtureXunit(
    Generator<int> generator)
{
    var numbers = generator.Where(x => x != 0).Distinct().Take(2);
    // -> 72, 117
}
```

Comment: This will work, but isn't the requested behaviour the *default* behaviour of AutoFixture?

Comment: OMG, indeed. I was tricked when I first read the original question. [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32781002/how-to-get-autofixture-create-an-integer-that-is-0-and-not-another-number/32782299?noredirect=1#comment53403678_32781002) should be the answer, as commented by @AlexanderW. Good catch! Thank you for pointing that out.

Comment: @NikosBaxevanis You're right, and I've unaccepted your answer. I cannot accept Mark's comment, since it's a comment, of course. Maybe Mark can "promote" his comment, so I can accept it ;)