# AutoFixture for number ranges

Tags: c#, autofixture

Is there an easy way to do this with AutoFixture?

```cs
var myInt = fixture.Create<int>(min, max);
```

I would like to know whether or not this is possible with AutoFixture or if I have to instantiate a random object and do the work myself.

In case this is not possible, is there a good reason for not having this feature that I am missing here?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, there is:

```cs
// Install-Package AutoFixture.Xunit - or -
// Install-Package AutoFixture.Xunit2

using System;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
using Xunit;

[Theory, AutoData]
public void ActualIsInTestRange([Range(99, 111)]int actual)
{
    Assert.InRange(actual, 99, 111);
}
```

Comment: I don't get the answer. If my understanding is right, the question asks for a way to create a value in a specified range. But the answer is about checking that a value is in a specifier range ...

Comment: The check is there for you to see what's going on, that the `actual` value was indeed generated in the specified range.

Comment: This does not answer the question. Instead it shows how to do it using a different library.

Comment: As an alternative, you may use the built-in `Generator<T>` and LINQ, as I've answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32782299/467754).

Answer (score 17):

As a one-off you could just do:

```
var value = fixture.Create<int>() % (max - min + 1) + min;
```

As a more re-usable approach, you could write an extension method as follows:

```
public static class FixtureExtensions
{
    public static int CreateInt(this IFixture fixture, int min, int max)
    {
        return fixture.Create<int>() % (max - min + 1) + min;
    }
}
```

Which can then be used as follows:

```
var value = fixture.CreateInt(min, max);
```

Comment: I think this does work for negative min and max, as long as min < max. 

One drawback compared with AutoFixture's usual behavior, however, is that there is no attempt to return distinct values in consecutive calls.

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be directly supported but one thing you can do is sort values that you generate.

For example, if you generate 5 values and then sort them, you can select the 1th and 3th items as the range, and you then have other values before, inside, and after the range. If desired this can be encapsulated into a class that takes an `IFixture` in its constructor (and you could maybe parameterize the number of outside and inside values).

```cs
var fixture = new Fixture();
var values = f.CreateMany<int>(5).OrderBy(x => x).ToArray();

var outsideSmall = values[0];
var start = values[1];
var inside = values[2];
var end = values[3];
var outsideBig = values[4];
```

With this approach everything stays both arbitrary and distinct.

(This works if you can make the range itself arbitrary; if you can't this might not work.)

Answer (score -2):

You can use extension method like this:

```
public static int CreateNumebrFromRange(this IFixture fixture,int min, int max)
{
   var radom = new Random();
   return radom.Next(min, max);
}
```

Comment: This is not an appropriate use of an extension method. The method signature indicates that it extends `IFixture`, but the method isn't actually doing anything with that type at all, i.e. it's not really extending that type. You could just as well have a static helper class that does the same. See @peterholmes' answer for an appropriate extension method implementation.