# Customizing AutoFixure using FromSeed Causes Exception

Tags: c#, unit-testing, autofixture

Given the two classes:

```
class Foo
{
    ...
}

class Bar
{
    public Foo FooBar { get; set; }
}
```

I have set up the following test:

```
void Test()
{
    var fixture = new Fixture();

    fixture.Customize<Foo>(x => x.FromSeed(TestFooFactory));

    var fooWithoutSeed = fixture.Create<Foo>();
    var fooWithSeed = fixture.Create<Foo>(new Foo());

    var bar = fixture.Create<Bar>(); //error occurs here
}

Foo TestFooFactory(Foo seed)
{
    //do something with seed...

    return new Foo();
}
```

I can create `Foo` objects directly with and without seed values without any problem.  But once I try to create a `Bar` object that has a `Foo` property, I get an `ObjectCreationException`:

> The decorated ISpecimenBuilder could not create a specimen based on the request: Foo. This can happen if the request represents an interface or abstract class; if this is the case, register an ISpecimenBuilder that can create specimens based on the request. If this happens in a strongly typed Build expression, try supplying a factory using one of the IFactoryComposer methods.

I'd expect `TestFooFactory` to get passed a `null` seed value during the creation of `Bar`, just as when I created `Foo` without a seed value. Am I doing something wrong, or could this be a bug?

In my real-world scenario, I want to customize how AutoFixture would use seeded values for certain objects when I pass seeded values in, but I still want AutoFixture to default to normal behavior if no seed is provided.

Comment: Crossposted to GitHub: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/467

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The way you're customizing the `Fixture` to use seed values [is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28462933/what-does-createmany-with-seed-do/28475970#28475970).

The behavior you're seeing is a consequence of how the `FromSeed` customization modifies the AutoFixture pipeline. If you're interested in reading up on the details, I've described them [here](https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/issues/467#issuecomment-155733721).

As a workaround, you can use a custom specimen builder for seeded requests like this one:

```
public class RelaxedSeededFactory<T> : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    private readonly Func<T, T> create;

    public RelaxedSeededFactory(Func<T, T> factory)
    {
        this.create = factory;
    }

    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        if (request != null && request.Equals(typeof(T)))
        {
            return this.create(default(T));
        }

        var seededRequest = request as SeededRequest;

        if (seededRequest == null)
        {
            return new NoSpecimen(request);
        }

        if (!seededRequest.Request.Equals(typeof(T)))
        {
            return new NoSpecimen(request);
        }

        if ((seededRequest.Seed != null)
            && !(seededRequest.Seed is T))
        {
            return new NoSpecimen(request);
        }

        var seed = (T)seededRequest.Seed;

        return this.create(seed);
    }
}
```

You can then use it to create objects of type `Foo` like this:

```
fixture.Customize<Foo>(c => c.FromFactory(
    new RelaxedSeededFactory<Foo>(TestFooFactory)));
```

This customization will pass `default(Foo)` – that is `null` – as a seed to the `TestFooFactory` factory function when populating properties of type `Foo`.

Comment: That works like a charm!  Thanks for the workaround.

Comment: I updated the custom `RelaxedSeededFactory` specimen builder with a _better_ approach. Instead of handling all requests, it will only handle seeded and non-seeded requests for `T`.

Comment: Just as an update, AutoFixture 3.36.12 fixes this issue: https://github.com/AutoFixture/AutoFixture/commit/c7ce7d239a26fd7aef8c464ba214c366681d0886. Thanks @Enrico!